# Page refresh WP PHP

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, caching

On Siteground I have installed WP and i have created a folder called 'test' in the same directory of 'wp-admin', 'wp-content' and 'wp-includes'. I have also created my own database that is not connected to the wp_database. In the test folder there are some PHP test pages to interact with my own database. The problem is that everytime i want to edit or add something on my own database throught this PHP test pages, the user-interface dont refresh the content; I have to press F5 everytimes to see the changes.

I'm thinking that it could be a cache problem related either to my browser or wordpress but I'm not sure. I have tried to clean my browser cache but nothing changed. The code below is an example of a PHP test page (test.php)

```php
<?php
  $con_my_db = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

  require( '../wp-load.php' );
  if(isset($_GET['add']){
    if($_POST){
      $insertquery = "INSERT INTO suppliers(name, code, address, phone) VALUES 
 ('$company' ,'$code' ,'$address' ,'$phone')";

      $resultinsertquery = $con->query($insertquery);
      if($resultinsertquery){
    echo 'Added';
      }else{
    echo 'Error';
      }
    } 
  }
?>
<a href="test.php">Back</a>
<form action="test.php?add=1" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="name"><br>
  <input type="text" name="code"><br>
  <input type="text" name="address"><br>
  <input type="text" name="phone"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
  }else{    
   $suppliers = $con->query("SELECT * FROM suppliers");
?>

<a href="test.php?add=1">Add supplier</a>
<table>
    .... list of the suppliers (avoided useless code)
</table>

<?php } ?>
```

After submitting the form and retrieving the "Added" output, I press the Back link to view the list of suppliers, but it dosen't show the new supplier just added. Refreshing the browser page it works. The problem is that i dont want to refresh the page everytime to see the changes done. How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

you are not seeing the updated data because the layout will not update automatically after the data entry. you are checking the $_GET["add"] whenever the form is submitted so the else part will not run at that time and when you refresh the page at that time the $_GET["add"] variable will not be set and the list of the updated suppliers will be fetched from database...

if you don't want to refresh the page every time you add a new supplier either you have to use the ajax to submit form and refresh the layout or add this line `header("Refresh:0; url=test.php");` after `echo("added");` it will automatically refresh the page after successful entry so you don't have to refresh the page manually...

or you can move the `$suppliers = $con->query("SELECT * FROM suppliers");` out of the else part and remove the else block so it will fetch the data from database every time..

Comment: text.php has 2 different layout, one that show the suppliers table (no GET parameters), and the other one that show the form to add a new supplier (GET['add'] parameter). I think that every time i add a new supplier and then i go back (through the "Back" link) to the suppliers list, it should show all of them.

Comment: No, your layout won't be refreshed if you are going back through back button hitting back button will only bring you back the previous layout from browser cache. you have to refresh page to get the updated data from your db.  you can learn this thing by google search also if you are facing any difficulties applying the changes i suggested then feel free to ask anytime..